# php Mysqli use_result limit oddity

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, limit

Ok so I have an odd odd situation

I have some code that looks something like this

```
public function select($sql, $params = false)
{
    $output = false;

    $this->_query = $this->escapeInto($sql, $params);


    $this->_mysqli->real_query($this->_query);

    $result = $this->_mysqli->use_result();
    return $result;
}
```

now when I pass in the following query

```
$this->_query = "SELECT * from bookings  ORDER BY booking_id ASC limit 38500,500";
```

and the whole function never returns it will get to the end of the function and I can print debug there but it never returns.

However if I send any other query it works fine. Both of these work and all increments of 500 to this point work.

```
$this->_query = "SELECT * from bookings  ORDER BY booking_id ASC limit 38501,500";
$this->_query = "SELECT * from bookings  ORDER BY booking_id ASC limit 38500,501";
```

I have no issue with any other query just this one and mysqli appears to be working fine
its just wont exit from this function. I am assuming its an issue with mysqli but cannot find any issues like this out there.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get when you enter those queries directly into MySQL?

Comment: fair question. It works fine I get exactly what your would expect.

Comment: In that case it might be a PHP bug.

Answer (score 0):

When LIMIT a large offset, mysql will almost certainly need to do full table scan to determine the order, and usually can get time-out on big table.

It is pretty much what happen during the first query.

For subsequent queries, where the cache is already in placed, it will be fast
(The PHP timeout does not stop mysql, it still process the calculation in background)

Comment: I don't think its a mysql issue directly as the query works fine directly in mysql just not when run as above.